# What's the difference between 'ANY' and 'EXISTS' in sql-server

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I'm running

```
select code from account where exists (select account from store)
except 
select code from account where code = any (select account from store)
```

it brings me 2 results which means that they are not the same. From my research, I haven't found any difference between them. 'Any' is rarely used from what I can find. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: `= any` is the same as `in` which is why you never see it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two queries are quite different.

The first query returns *all* rows or *no* rows depending on whether the subquery returns any rows at all or no rows.

You intend a correlated subquery:

```
select code from account where exists (select 1 from store where store.account = account.code)
```

These should be equivalent.